# What's a word to describe the whole something is a part of?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that means the whole something is a part of; e.g.

An element is a *constituent* of a list; "a whole's *constituent*" refers to an element.
The list is the _____ of an element; "an element's ____" refers to the whole.

Aggregate was my original thought, but I'm not sure it fully works since it's better used with all the elements rather than one specific one; this can be seen in "the elements' aggregate".

Comment: An element's classification, parent, etc? You haven't been very specific about what is meant by 'element'.

Comment: Thanks for including a sample sentence, as is required for word requests! I think we're still not getting it, though, because it's so generic. Could you try for a more specific one? Does "The novel is the ___ of the chapter" work? I'm afraid there isn't going to be any one word, so much as many that could work but bring in other connotations or contextual uses...

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. Sorry for being so generic in the original question, but the exact use case is very similar to Andy's suggested example, and is related to financial products. Though I'm not sure it's super relevant here, I'll provide a little context: a combo is a financial product that contains many constituent products called singles. I'm looking for a word to reference a combo from one of these constituents; for example, "A single's ____ combo", intending to reference the combo that contains this single.

Comment: *a combo is a financial product that contains many constituent products called singles* So the term *product* is applied to both the whole and the part?  Are some financial products composed of only one part?  Can the same part appear in more than one whole?  Please, don't try to explain (if you care to explain at all) in a comment, edit your question to be more complete.

Comment: Didn't want to get too much in the nitty gritty, but if you are curious, https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/combination.asp provides a more precise and rigorous explanation at the expense of additional jargon. That being said, a good example of a reasonable word to substitute in Andy's example "The novel is the ___ of the chapter" a few replies above would be more than sufficient.

Comment: I despair of folk who ask for precise words to fit into particular situations but refrain from precision in their descriptions of those situations.  You're asking us to find a peg to fit a hole, but keeping us in the dark about whether you have a square hole or a round one.  Don't fret, I despair of so much of C21.

Comment: My intention was never to get a specific answer, or an exact peg to fit the hole I'm trying to fill. A better way to word my original question would ask for an amorphous peg that fits in many holes similar to the one I provided in the comments above to a reasonable extent. The word "parent" suggested above by Weather Vane acts as a reasonable answer to this, and is probably as close to what I want as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of commercial deals, such as in the case of this financial product referred to in the comments, it seems that the word "package" is proper.

> ([OALD, package 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/package_1?q=package/2)) a set of items or ideas that must be bought or accepted together

As "combination" means "put together", the term "package combo" seem very much redundant, so given the understanding that each combination is a package, the term "single's package" could be used.